# Find minimum number of columns that identify uniqely all rows

Tags: t-sql, ssms, primary-key, clustered-primary-key

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

I've a table and I want to find a Primary Key for this table.

Can I write a script in T-SQL that finds which columns (and I want that the number of columns is minimum) identify uniqely all rows?

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically identify a natural primary key based on the contents of a table? That isn't something that makes sense to do as the data in a table can change any time, unless you have something like a clustered index or unique constraint in place already, in which case you'd presumably know the primary key already.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Yes. I've a table without constraints and I want to find an automatic method to identify a natural primary key. But you are right, this doesn't make sense because data can change any time. So the only solution is to know the real meaning behind each column and use intuition? So using `SELECT DISTINCT` to check for a primary key is meaningless because data change any time? Is there exist an heuristic to find a primary key not knowing the origin of a table?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You can edit your question to add this additional information.

Comment: The only way we can help you with this is if you give us some idea of what the data actually is - if, say, vehicles, we could suggest VIN/registration, if people, then SS number? We need some more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't reasonable to try to do this. I'm going to assume there is no existing primary key / unique constraints existing already. The problems with this approach are:

1. Data can change at any time. If you found a unique set of values, there is no guaranteeing that they will remain unique
2. Analyzing the data to find this could be *extremely* costly from a time/resources perspective and would require extensive customization for each specific table.
3. Figuring out how many columns actually make up the key by their values is extremely hard (you'd probably have to take a brute force approach) as you can add any x number of columns to a key and still have unique values when looking at them as a set.

In some cases there may be something obvious, like an `ID` column, which is *probably* a primary key candidate. However, if no primary keys or unique constraints are defined, it is always best to double check with a data owner / steward.

In most cases, context, the business, and/or requirements will define what unique keys are. It is not something I'd ever advise inferring just from the data unless you are extremely familiar with the data domain and even then you should refer to a subject matter expert to validate.

Comment: Nicely explained. Also a Unique value at times can have NULL which is not possible for a primary key.Only the Application\Data owner can guide on which values will remain unique throughout without accepting NULL and then this can be made Primary key.